# Vue.js2 - Array contains __ob__ : Observer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

(Probably) a beginners question regarding vue.js. I'm trying to display Data using the CanvasJS Library received via websocket. Working with the data works fine until I start using vue components. To make myself clearer:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      cartesian: null,
      ws: null
    }
  },

  methods: {

    fillData(res) {
     var data = JSON.parse(res.data)

     var buffer = data.mdi
     console.log(buffer)

     this.cartesian = data.mdi
     console.log(this.cartesian)
    }

  },

  mounted() {
    this.ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:1111')
    this.ws.onmessage = this.fillData
  }
}
```

The line `console.log(data.mdi)` outputs `{0: Array(256), 1: Array(256), 2: Array(256), 3: Array(256)}`. This is exactly what I'm expecting and what works with CanvasJS.
The line `console.log(this.cartesian)` however outputs `{__ob__: Observer}`. A far as I understand, this has to do with the reactiveness of vue.js. Unfortunately I cannot use the contents of `this.cartesian` with CanvasJS because it does not show any data.
As I don't see any other way to display my data other than using `this.cartesian` I'm hoping for help regarding what I might be doing wrong here or how to access the data in `this.cartesian` as I can see its there when inspecting it in my browser.

Comment: `{__ob__: Observer}` is just an indication that `cartesian` is a property observed by Vue. There should be a carat next to it that you can expand to see the values. There is no reason this should interfere with your library code. I expect there is something else going on.

Comment: You were right. I hadn't found the right way to dynamically populate the Chart with my Data. `{__ob__: Observer}` does not seem to interfere. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Because `cartesian` is part of your component data, it becomes reactive by adding getters and setters.

You can use some tricks to get around this intended feature, but that's usually not needed if you use the *object spread destructuring* feature of ES6.

```
let cartesianObject = {...this.cartesian};
console.log(cartesianObject);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The problem lay somewhere else. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone running into a similar problem: The `{__ob__: Observer}` did not interfere with the CanvasJS Library. I could have used `this.cartesian` without problem. I just hadn't found the correct way to populate my Chart with Data.
The console.log might be misleading here, but you should be able to use your data regardless of the `{__ob__: Observer}` in the same ways you could in plain js.